# Is it possible to show a successful logout message?

Tags: redirection

When site members click logout they are taken back to the homepage.

I'd like to redirect the user back to the login page but with a "You're logged out" type of message.

Is something like this possible yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible yet, but a quick plugin would make this possible. It would just be a controller with a logout action. You'd be able to call the action as a url with:

```
/actions/[PluginHandle]/[ControllerName]/[ActionName]
```

Then you can logout the user the same way Craft does in their controller and edit the redirect as you see fit. Something like this:

```
craft()->userSession->logout(false);
$this->redirect('?status=logout');
```

This would log them out and then send them to the homepage with a query attached to the end.

Comment: I've setup a simple plugin. My Controller is called DelaneyMethod_MembersControllor with an action called actionLogout. In my form I have this: delaneymethod/members/logout but I get "Page Not Found, Unable to resolve the request "delaneymethod/members/logout".

Comment: I also see you have suggested /actions/[PluginHandle]/[ControllerName]/[ActionName] and not /[PluginHandle]/[ControllerName]/[ActionName] as action URL ?

Comment: Hey Sean, Craft's controllers are triggered when the first URL segment is [‘actions’](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers#how-controller-actions-fit-into-routing) (by default) . You can generate a URL using the actionUrl function, i.e. `{{ actionUrl('delaneyMethod/members/logout') }}`

Comment: Yes, I know but I'm submitted a form in this case... and I have an action field.

Comment: I've got it working. I was calling "delaneymethod/members/logout" not "delaneyMethod/members/logout". Simple things that the eye doesn't catch... Thanks.

Comment: Ah right, okay. Is the controller spelt with an ‘o’ a typo in your first comment? Also you'll need to use the correct camelCasing for action URIs, i.e. ‘delaneyMethod/members/logout’ instead of ‘delaneymethod/members/logout’.

Comment: Haha good stuff, glad you're sorted.