# How do I set where the user is sent from a custom login form?

Tags: plugin-development, login

Is there a way to send the user to a different page than the control panel when logging in from a custom login form?

I've tried..

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/login">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="apply">
```

I've also tried setting the returnUrl session in a login event within a plugin. There's a bit left to do in the init function but you get the idea. Currently the code should redirect all logins.

```
public function init()
{
    craft()->on('userSession.onLogin', function(Event $event) {
        // load the user info and determine user group
        // if part of applicant user group
        // load any existing unfinished applications
        // set a session for the unfinished application
        // redirect to /apply which should load the unfinished application
        craft()->session['returnUrl'] = "/apply";
    });
}
```

Comment: In the end this ended up being a small error with the path in the returnUrl. Simply changing it to craft()->session['returnUrl'] = "apply"; appears to have solved the problem. I'm still curious if there's a way to set this in the custom login template or if it has to be done in a plugin.

Answer (score 4):

You can set a variable in your craft/config/general.php. Here is the option taken from the default config file which is located here `craft/app/etc/config/defaults/general.php`:

**Updated:**

```
/**
 * The path that users should be redirected to after logging in from the front-end site.
 *
 * This setting will also come into effect if the user visits the Login page (as specified by the loginPath config
 * setting) when they are already logged in.
 */
'postLoginRedirect' => '',
```

From that page you can also easily route them to another page based on conditionals in twig using `{% if something %}{% redirect url %}{% endif %}`.

And although I haven't tried this personally, it looks like ([based on this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/71/is-it-possible-to-show-a-successful-logout-message/77#77)) you can redirect from within your plugin using the following (perhaps only from a controller however):

```
$this->redirect('/apply');
```

I also see in UserSessionService.php line 371 the following which should also work:

```
$url = UrlHelper::getUrl(craft()->config->getLoginPath());
craft()->request->redirect($url);
```

Comment: Isn't account activation when an account is initially activated? Or does it refer to when the user logs in? Is there a way to set different redirect paths for different forms with the config file method?

Comment: Unfortunately $this->redirect('/apply'); did not work in my plugin. Perhaps $this->redirect() can only be used in a controller. It throws errors when used in an init() function within the main plugin file.

Comment: You're right on both counts. Sorry. I grabbed the wrong variable. Use `postLoginRedirect` instead. I have updated the answer.